# Custom directive to replace @mouseenter + @mouseleave event?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vuejs3, vue-directives

I'm having lots of elements on which `@mouseenter` set a value to `true` and `@mouseleave` sets it to `false`. Basically what I need is a way to set a reactive variable to `true` if the mouse hovers the element.

I've been trying to figure out how to write such `custom directive` from the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/custom-directives.html#introduction) but it only mentions how to use `.focus() js function` on an element. Which js functions would be used for said directive?

Something like:

```
const vHover = {
    mounted: (el) => {
        el.addEventListener('mouseenter', state.hover=true)
        el.addEventListener('mouseleave', state.hover=false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you having a problem with what you're doing? Those are the relevant events.

Comment: Though you need to pass a function to `addEventListener` so `() => state.hover=true`. [playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqFUsFOwzAM/RUrB9JJLAWJU7UhIYTEgT8gHLrFWzvSJErcbqjqv+N0G+KARNRD/WI/Pz9nFE8hqKFHUYlV2sY2ECSkPjxq13bBR4IRIu5ggl30HUhOldppV5aQqCbUziJB4weMsM6Zxa62CRc5Z+tdIhheL5ejdsCn870jNBUUaBewfrzi+aBVtTEvAzp6axOhw1hILkjICEZ5C8VcMvdTQ217XFPsc7v/KSzWA/5JcZWc6yft+FuVZzPYBg4Iu2B5WI4AVqYdYFieR64SfVlca/E+ygbbfUOyAvlwF07cSB5bQ81vYOOj4TEYuQ8nSN62hmGlVDHT3dyMclNvP/eRPTLP3vo5N6KR0wKmDy1mBQCzjpKFcLwqf+SJW3Fe2rKrgzok73its736cpG0qK6Ga8HLzLEWDVFIVVmm3TY/hkNSPu5L/lORl9V2qDB1y030x8SmHZglU2SrxPQN59y/iA==)

Comment: With cleanup: [playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do something like:

```
app.directive('hover', {
    created(el, binding) {
        const callback = binding.value
        el.onmouseenter = () => callback(true)
        el.onmouseleave = () => callback(false)
    },
    unmounted(el) {
        el.onmouseenter = null
        el.onmouseleave = null
    }
})
```

Template:

```
<button v-hover="onHoverChange">Example</button>
```

Methods:

```
onHoverChange(isHovered) {
    console.log(isHovered)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not the intended use of directives. The value of the state cannot be mutated within the directive. You can pass the variable through the `binding`, but you cannot update it.

> binding: an object containing the following properties.
>
> - `value`: The value passed to the directive. For example in v-my-directive="1 + 1", the value would be 2.
> - `oldValue`: The previous value, only available in beforeUpdate and updated. It is available whether or not the value has changed.

so if you do `el.addEventListener('mouseenter', binding.hover=true)`, as you may have noticed, it will not update the state.

However, if we use the internals (PSA: *though not recommended since they could potentially change at any time*), you could get instance using the `vnode`, and use the `binding.arg` to denote which Proxy (`state`)

so you could get the reactive variable with `vnode.el.__vueParentComponent.data[binding.arg]`

```
<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      state: { hover:false }
    }
  },
  directives: {
    hover: {
      mounted(el, binding, vnode) {
        el.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
          vnode.el.__vueParentComponent.data[binding.arg].hover = true
        })
        el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
          vnode.el.__vueParentComponent.data[binding.arg].hover = false
        })
      },
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <h1 v-hover:state="state">HOVER {{ state }}</h1>
</template>
```

[SFC playground link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqtUk1rwzAM/SvCl7WQOvQa0sIYhR0GGzvsMo/iNmqTkthBdrJByH+f4vSLbYwdFgK2LOn56T134rauZdugSETqtlTUfqkMftSWPGS4003poVMGINNeT6ZhC0DoGzJjYvic1x4T6CC3LVKy06VD6MdsWPooYBSEW1+06Lh2zI4NF6TKNsZjNsEygk1hssLsI2iNzXB6KQLAUuosW7Vo/EPhPBqkyQ33OuQTpJsIJlNYLK9bYISR3Lpe88RPmrj2zla1NbyRw4Cvxyulpv2bDNxgAZ4avOD007/QKFG3+L80gqo/8RjFPSmtDP9pfDaTA49VXbJDHAGk+Rza2ah78G2hRFiVWN4/vqyeoetGQ6Hv0zifc1caX0GISBTMlvys0rU8OGv48YQJ1THhlDhbqgQPOcRK5N7XLoljt9sOT+7gpKV9zDtJbHpRsSiumm3IvjskBlbiOFjAiPmQOc9YrgwJ6TfML6XfcE9Cif4T8tb+Jg==)

of course you might want to add the `unmounted` and even consider adding `mouseleave` dynamically only when `mouseenter` fires

Answer (score 0):

This is how it can be done inside the component:

```
const vHover = {
    mounted: (el) => {
        el.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {state.hover=true})
        el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {state.hover=false})
    },
    unmount: (el) => {
        el.removeEventListener('mouseenter', () => {state.hover=true})
        el.removeEventListener('mouseleave', () => {state.hover=false})
    }
}
```